# Sacar valores maximos de un COUNT en mysql

Tags: mysql

buenas tardes

Vereis, la consulta es esta -> 4. Nombre de la canción que maś unidades ha vendido.

El tema es que estoy intentando sacar los valores maximos de un count en una subconsulta, tal que asi

```
SELECT Track.Name, COUNT(invoiceline.Quantity) FROM track
INNER JOIN invoiceline ON track.TrackId = invoiceline.TrackId
GROUP BY invoiceline.TrackID
HAVING COUNT(invoiceline.Quantitly) > ALL 
(SELECT COUNT(Quantity) FROM invoiceline
GROUP BY TrackId)
```

Se me acaban las ideas jaja si me podeis ayudar, lo agradeceria

Comment: Sería bueno que publicaras la estructura de la tabla/tablas involucradas.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Track.Name, MAX(invoiceline.Quantity) 
FROM track INNER JOIN invoiceline 
ON track.TrackId =invoiceline.TrackId
GROUP BY invoiceline.TrackID
```

Comment: Hola Fernando, las preguntas que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor, edítala para añadir más información: ¿qué hace ese código? ¿cómo funciona? ¿en qué se diferencia del código que no funciona de la pregunta? Lee [answer] para más información y consejos.